# Java runs out of memory. Is this not a memory leak?

Tags: java, docker, kubernetes, memory-leaks, grafana

I have assigned our Java program 2GB of memory. During the hours a particular thread is running, memory steadily and linearly increases until Kubernetes kills it because it reaches the 2GB limit I assigned. Of course we were thinking of a memory leak, but we see something like this all the time in the gc log:

```
[7406.381s][info][gc] GC(8326) Pause Full (System.gc()) 130M->65M(214M) 157.995ms
```

1. Since the memory increases linearly while these logs indicates that the heap memory does not increase, is it useless to investigate memory leaks?
2. What could be other likely causes of the increasing memory?

Some background info:

There are no logs that say the container was stopped or killed. There are also no events in k8s (however "restarts" = 1). The above log line was the last log line before we see (in Graylog) that Spring Boot / Tomcat is starting (hence it must have been restarted). We see this happening exactly at the time when the memory graph reaches the 2GB line in Grafana. Without Grafana it would have taken a while before we figured out it was something related to memory.

Kubernetes deploy yml part:

```
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: ... (omitted)
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 1200m
              memory: 2Gi
            requests:
              cpu: 50m
              memory: 50Mi
```

Last line of Dockerfile:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-Xmx2G", "-verbose:gc", "-jar", "/backend.jar"]
```

where "-verbose:gc" causes the log lines like the line I quoted above.

It takes a while to reproduce the problem, but we did that a couple of times.

We're using Java 11.

Comment: You probably have a memory leak. Can you attach e.g. visualvm to the process to visualize?

Comment: Does your application use any native libraries? That is, libraries that are dependent on some `.so` or `.dll`? Keep in mind that if the total memory you give your app is 2G, the max heap size has to be lower, to allow for non-heap memory.

Comment: Is the traffic to application growing or is it stand-alone application

Comment: As @RealSkeptic indicates your PermGen could be filling up.

Comment: @davidmontoyago There is no more PermGen. It has been superseded by Metaspace since Java 8.

Comment: @CptDolphin There's no traffic towards the application, but it fetches data from databases and images form shared disks and writes to elasticsearch and images to another shared disk.

Comment: maybe the data in db ain't indexed or just db can't handle it (check cpu) and the queue is growing ? just a thought

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you have a leak at all, you are just using the options wrong. With `-Xmx2G` you are telling Java that it can use up to 2G for the heap. At the same time you are telling Kubernetes that the absolute limit for memory is 2Gi. Now, Java uses memory that is not on the heap, so when it tries to expand the heap to 2G it runs out and the pod is killed.

To fix the problem make sure that you allow a reasonable margin for the memory that is outside the heap. Increase the Kubernetes limit to 3G temporarily and then scale it down when you know how much native memory you need. I would guess that 2.5G is a reasonable level, but that is just a guess. Alternatively you can decrease the Java heap size and run with a 1.5G heap (or less) to leave some room for the native memory.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the Java K,M,G are actually Ki,Mi,Gi. That is, `-xmx2G` is the same as the 2Gi that were allocated.